# Sequentially number groups of values (including repeats)

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have the following table:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Temp
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    ID INT,
    Category VARCHAR(100),
    [Date] DATE
)
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES 
(1,'AAA','20200625'),
(1,'BBB','20200626'),
(1,'BBB','20200627'),
(1,'AAA','20200628'),
(1,'AAA','20200629'),
(1,'BBB','20200630'),
(1,'AAA','20200701'),
(2,'AAA','20200625'),
(2,'BBB','20200626'),
(2,'BBB','20200627'),
(2,'AAA','20200628'),
(2,'AAA','20200629'),
(2,'BBB','20200630'),
(2,'AAA','20200701')
```

I can't figure out how to assign a sequential integer to the categories like this:

```
ID  Category    Date        GroupNumber
-------------------------------------------
1   AAA         25/06/2020  1
1   BBB         26/06/2020  2
1   BBB         27/06/2020  2
1   AAA         28/06/2020  3
1   AAA         29/06/2020  3
1   BBB         30/06/2020  4
1   AAA         01/07/2020  5
2   AAA         25/06/2020  1
2   BBB         26/06/2020  2
2   BBB         27/06/2020  2
2   AAA         28/06/2020  3
2   AAA         29/06/2020  3
2   BBB         30/06/2020  4
2   AAA         01/07/2020  5
```

I've tried different combinations of window functions without success. The goal is roll the data up so that it look like this:

```
ID  Category    Date        DateFrom    DateTo
--------------------------------------------------
1   AAA         25/06/2020  25/06/2020  25/06/2020
1   BBB         26/06/2020  26/06/2020  27/06/2020
1   AAA         28/06/2020  28/06/2020  29/06/2020
1   BBB         30/06/2020  30/06/2020  30/06/2020
1   AAA         01/07/2020  01/07/2020  01/07/2020
2   AAA         25/06/2020  25/06/2020  25/06/2020
2   BBB         26/06/2020  26/06/2020  27/06/2020
2   AAA         28/06/2020  28/06/2020  29/06/2020
2   BBB         30/06/2020  30/06/2020  30/06/2020
2   AAA         01/07/2020  01/07/2020  01/07/2020
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-island problem, where you want to group together "adjacent rows". The simplest approach to get the final result you are looking for probably is to use the difference between row numbers to identify the groups:

```
select id, category, min(date) datefrom, max(date) dateto
from (
    select t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by id order by date) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by id, category order by date) rn2
    from #temp t
) t
group by id, category, rn1 - rn2
order by id, datefrom
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=29149c7ca49ccb3e9fe268d0c37d89f1)**:

```
id | category | datefrom   | dateto    
-: | :------- | :--------- | :---------
 1 | AAA      | 2020-06-25 | 2020-06-25
 1 | BBB      | 2020-06-26 | 2020-06-27
 1 | AAA      | 2020-06-28 | 2020-06-29
 1 | BBB      | 2020-06-30 | 2020-06-30
 1 | AAA      | 2020-07-01 | 2020-07-01
 2 | AAA      | 2020-06-25 | 2020-06-25
 2 | BBB      | 2020-06-26 | 2020-06-27
 2 | AAA      | 2020-06-28 | 2020-06-29
 2 | BBB      | 2020-06-30 | 2020-06-30
 2 | AAA      | 2020-07-01 | 2020-07-01
```